# How to create global interwiki repository with wikibase

Tags: mediawiki

I have installed 4 mediawiki wikis. And one mediawiki with wikibase installed, this wiki is being used for the global userdatabase and some other stuff. Now we have all our interwiki links like this

```
[[en:Main Page]]
```

However we want to have a global database with all the interwiki links, they have did this on wikipedia too.

http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q727#sitelinks-wikipedia

So what extension do we need for this?

Comment: You need to install [Wikibase Client](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client) on the other 3 wikis.

Answer (score 0):

As Tgr wrote: You need to install [Wikibase Client](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client) on the other 3 wikis.